# Can I get only URIs that return views?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I need to give URIs names to display them in some analytics dashboard (Each URI that has a view usually has an actual name and also needs to be translated to other languages)

What I did now was to save all the GET routes as a JSON in a file, and extract only the URIs:

```
php artisan route:list -- method=GET --json
```

I then saved the output in a file, and decoded the JSON and extracted only the URIs:

```
$uris_json = file_get_contents("/path/to/routes/file");
$uris_array = json_decode($uris_json, true);
$uris = array_column($uris_array, 'uri');
```

Now I can see all the GET uris I have and manually give each a name.

But, some `GET` routes don't really have views so I don't need them, but there are hundreds and I have to check each one to see who really has a view.

Is there a way to check which GET route eventually leads to a view?

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to directly determine if a specific route returns a view without knowing the specifics of your application. However, Laravel views are often returned directly from a controller method but they can also be returned directly from the routes file. You might can determine which routes return a view, you will need to inspect your controllers as well as your routes file.

Let's assume you're following the Laravel convention of placing views in the resources/views directory and calling them in your controller methods with the view() function.

This solution includes creating a command that checks all your GET routes, accesses the controllers, and checks if there is a view() function call inside. This is a basic check and may not catch all scenarios such as dynamic view calls or views returned from other classes or functions but it will provide a starting point.

Here's a simplified way to create such a command:

```
class CheckViewRoutes extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'route:check-views';
    protected $description = 'Check GET routes that return a view';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle(Router $router)
    {
        /** @var Route[] $routes */
        $routes = array_filter($router->getRoutes()->getRoutes(), function (Route $route) {
            return in_array('GET', $route->methods());
        });

        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $uses = $route->action['uses'] ?? null;

            if (!is_string($uses)) {
                continue;
            }

            list($controller, $method) = Str::parseCallback($uses);

            try {
                $reflector = new ReflectionClass($controller);
                if (!$reflector->hasMethod($method)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $fileName = $reflector->getMethod($method)->getFileName();
                $fileContent = file_get_contents($fileName);

                if (Str::contains($fileContent, 'view(')) {
                    $this->info($route->uri() . ' seems to return a view');
                }

            } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4726a1bce9706083939a56b88b657a4c6fe83d9ae0543889df2938517ed1e4f5/{view?} seems to return a view
9Pq8Yo7DL7yGXAeqViGws7+5TF606asKyuEpGmCb9Sq6w0GIiG40/{view?} seems to return a view
api/payment/history seems to return a view
payment/gateway/{transaction}/on-the-go seems to return a view
payment/errors seems to return a view
payment/{key}/success seems to return a view
```